# Number Search with (^)carat in mongoDB does'nt work

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

unable to search in my mongoDB collection with data-type is Number and carat doesnt seem to work for me
 Search query

```
  db.collection.find({mobile : /^9/});
```

DB collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "Name" : "Mr.XXX",
    "mobile" : NumberLong(9876543210),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-07-09T07:21:45.552Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "Name" : "Mr.YYY",
    "mobile" : NumberLong(887654210),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

But the search result doesnt seem to work for mobile and it works for other dataTypes.

Comment: Regular expressions don't work on numbers they work on "strings". Standard operators won't work here.

Comment: @Blakes Seven Thanks for your reply....But is there any alternative available in mongodb as i need to search on keyup events on client side

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform a regex on a number value however, you should change your schema.

Mobile numbers regularly start with a `0` in many countries (UK for example) and do not follow the rules for a strict integer (which `NumberLong` is) nor are they are a strict size normally as such you should not be storing them as a number type but instead a string type, at which point you can regex on them.

As such, instead of trying to find some weird work around using aggregation or `$where`, both of which will result in a painful death you should instead change your schema to match the information you are actually entering.

Answer (score 0):

The data is "numeric" so a Regular expression does not work here, as they only work on "strings".

You can use JavaScript evaluation of [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)  for this, since JavaScript can cast the "type":

```js
db.collection.find(function() { return this.mobile.toString().match(/^9/) })
```

But that isn't a great idea since `$where` cannot use an index to match and relys on the coded condition to compare.

If you need to do this sort of matching then your "numeric" data needs to be a "string", or at least have something in the document with the "string" representation:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "Name" : "Mr.XXX",
    "mobile" : "9876543210",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-07-09T07:21:45.552Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Then your [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query works as expected when matching against a "string".

```js
db.collection.find({ "mobile": /^9/ })
```

Answer (score 0):

As per mongoDB [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) it said that **regex regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings in queries.** So first you should convert `mobile` to `String` using [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/), assuming your mobile number always `10` digit number.

This aggregation may slow but it satisfied your criteria, check below aggregation  query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
{
    "$project": {
        "mobileToString": {
            "$substr": [
                "$mobile",
                0,
                10
            ]
        },
        "Name": 1,
        "mobile": 1,
        "date": 1,
        "__v": 1
    }
},
{
    "$match": {
        "mobileToString": /^9/
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "Name": 1,
        "mobile": 1,
        "date": 1,
        "__v": 1
    }
}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: **If** mobile happens to be a standard length you mean. I can comment that I have heard various "threats" that this behavior of `$substr` is likely to be removed. Also, this is one case wthere the multiple pipelines used here looses to JavaScript processing on performance. The real message should always be "correct the data", rather than work around it.

Comment: @BlakesSeven you are right should correct data , but if OP don't have any option to updating the data and find out `match` conditions with same data type then above query help us , and I mentioned that this may slow but give expected output. So I already mentioned performance issues and I am not heard about `$substr` to removed . An one more thing I also run your query which return no any matching documents. And if only solution was to changed data then it sufficient to post comment to OP to changed data type.

Comment: But that **also should not** be using aggregation. This will "transform" every document in the collection and **then** run through the whole collection **again** just to test for a match using a regular expression. JavaScript processin is slower than native operators but **not** that much slower to warrant such brute force. The JavaScript expression would run rings around this, therefore it would be preferable. But "fixing data" is always preferable.

Comment: Here is also an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484316/multi-sum-count-on-mongodb-sum-gender-and-total-all-results/31488590#31488590) of aggregate vs aggregate to that clearly shows just how pad putting in `$project` stages without consideration to performance can be. The only case `.aggregate()` could win here would be with a "single" `$redact` stage. But it is not possible at present to get a "logical" match on a regular expression within that operator.